# why the data not loaded in the table when the page in the print dialog

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem here
i make a page that have function for print page that contain of dynamic table. the print function method is open the page html that contain the dynamic table in the new tab then open the print dialog. the process going well but when i add the ajax call for displaying the data in the dynamic table. the data not displayed at the table in the print dialog..but when i cancel the print dialog and the page that must be printed show off the data is displaying there...

how to fix it.

this the picture of the page
[image]

[image]

i use this code for print that

```js
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    
 window.open('SPL.html','','height=650,width=1200').print();
 }
 
 </script>
```

Comment: you'll need to wait for the page to completely load - use the load event?

Comment: Simple, the printer dialog won´t run javascript. So you have to open it, wait for js finished and then then start the printer. This could be done by inserting the print() function at the end of your js script. Simply means, after the ajax return use window.print();

Comment: Try to use media query for print(part of CSS media queries)

Comment: @JaromandaX im just use window.open then url

Comment: @Doomenik what you mean? i didnt get it T_T.. can you give me an example

Comment: @MinervazMine It simple, can you post your SPL.html, inside of it you do some kind of ajax request. After you generated the content you have to call window.print. At the moment your doing this in your first page.

Comment: @MinervazMine So I gave you a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt provided yet the code of your generator, so I simply explain you why its not working and what you can do.

A good reference for window [Mozilla Window Open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

You can read there more details about possible functions and more. Your problem is, with:

```
window.open('SPL.html','','height=650,width=1200').print();
```

Directly after opening the file you call the print function, at this moment your script and ajax request don´t have finished yet. Thats why it just shows you the current state with the predefined html and css code.

So what you have to do is simply call print after it has finished. There are tons of ways to achieve this.

The simplest way would it to open it like this:

```
window.open('SPL.html','','height=650,width=1200')
```

Inside your SPL.html you stack your js script inside:

```
$(document).ready() {
 //Your Generator
}
```

This little piece keeps safe that all dependencys (external scripts and dom elements) are created before your generator runs and it gives us the possibility for the next function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  window.print()
});
```

This one is a version of the globalEventHandler [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload). It basicly ,if you read the documentation, fires after everything is loaded, including images, frames, objects and so on. And the tricky part also after `document.ready`, this makes it sure that our generator is finished before we run the print command.

I hope this helps, If you really want to stick the print command inside your first page I can give you an example of this too. But it is not as bullet prove as this solution. Ah and if you want to stick with @Saurabh solution you have to use `allow-modals` for your Iframe, if not it wouldn´t be possible to print. Is also mentioned in the official documentation.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because the page is not completely loaded before calling the print function.

Update: Using jQuery

**index.html**

```
 <html> 
    <head> 
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#loaderFrame').load(function(){
                var w = (this.contentWindow || this.contentDocument.defaultView);
                w.print();
            });
                $('#loaderFrame').attr('src', 'SPL.html');
            });
        });
      </script>
    <style>
         #loaderFrame{
            visibility: hidden;
            height: 1px;
            width: 1px;
         }
    </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <iframe id="loaderFrame" ></iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: now the page just loaded in a new page and not open the print dialog

Comment: i will try that

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console? Please post the error message here.